# How to batch edit jpeg images

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editing, automation

Is there some elegant way to edit the brightness / contrast of a batch of images?

I need to be able to see a real time preview of the effect of the brightness / contrast change on at least one of the images, and get the same edit to apply to the rest of the batch.

Comment: Wouldn't Adobe Lightroom be a good setup for this? I haven't personally used it but it seems like all of the professional photographers I know use it (and love it) for processing many images. I believe it will allow you to set a profile up for one image and then apply it to many ones.

Comment: Have you looked into [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488) with iPhoto at all?  I don't have my Mac in front of me, but that's where I'd probably start.